# Restore metrics after Google Cloud SQL (Postgres) crash

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

A couple of days our Google Cloud SQL instance "crashed" or at least was not responsive any longer. It recovered and works and all *Query Insights* and so on work again.

However, most metrics like *CPU utilization*, *Storage usage* and *Memory usage* are currently not available. I thought that would recover automatically as well but after 2 days I wonder if there needs to happen something manually.

Is there something I can do other than restarting the database (which would be only my last resort).

Comment: Are those metrics still not available? If so, could you try to check in the [Stackdrivers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring) if that data is available?

Comment: It seems to be working again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after waiting around 3 days the metrics are working again.